# ReorderListView in WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, user-controls

I love the controls from the [Bag-Of-Tricks](http://bot.codeplex.com).

I am interested in **modifying** the **ReorderListBox** control to **get a ReorderListView** control. However, simply **changing the base class from ListBox to ListView is not working**.

When I try to add a ReorderListView to XAML like this:

```
  <lib:ReorderListView Grid.Row="1">
        <ReorderListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Data1" />
            </GridView>
        </ReorderListView.View>
  </lib:ReorderListView>
```

I get an error ("The tag 'ReorderListView.View' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.)

How do I modify the ReorderListBox example to get this to work? Has anyone already succeeded in doing this?

Comment: ListView and ListBox are drastically different controls, so this will not be as simple as changing the base class. But based on your error alone it appears that you did not actually change the base class.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to specify the 'lib' namespace of your ReorderListView.View property

```
<lib:ReorderListView Grid.Row="1">
    <lib:ReorderListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Data1" />
        </GridView>
    </lib:ReorderListView.View>
```